# CakePHP joing two tables

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem in viewing my  data ,I need to return a year,ex(2010,2011,2012,2013) instead of returning the year id , I used contain but It did not work , what is the right way to displaying data ?!
Here is  the output array:array(

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'IndicatorDatum' => array(
            'id' => '188',
            'indicator_id' => '2',
            'report_year_id' => '2',
            'value' => '144063181',
            'comment' => '0',
            'reference' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'IndicatorDatum' => array(
            'id' => '163',
            'indicator_id' => '2',
            'report_year_id' => '3',
            'value' => '178104575',
            'comment' => '0',
            'reference' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'IndicatorDatum' => array(
            'id' => '137',
            'indicator_id' => '2',
            'report_year_id' => '4',
            'value' => '198637602',
            'comment' => '0',
            'reference' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'IndicatorDatum' => array(
            'id' => '5752',
            'indicator_id' => '2',
            'report_year_id' => '5',
            'value' => '1234',
            'comment' => null,
            'reference' => null
        )
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'IndicatorDatum' => array(
            'id' => '5694',
            'indicator_id' => '2',
            'report_year_id' => '6',
            'value' => '100',
            'comment' => '0',
            'reference' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        'IndicatorDatum' => array(
            'id' => '5271',
            'indicator_id' => '2',
            'report_year_id' => '6',
            'value' => '1',
            'comment' => '0',
            'reference' => '0'
        )
    )
)
```

Model

```
    public $belongsTo = array(

        'Indicator' => array(
            'className' => 'Indicator',
            'foreignKey' => 'indicator_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'ReportYear' => array(
            'className' => 'ReportYear',
            'foreignKey' => 'report_year_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Organisation' => array(
            'className' => 'Organisation',
            'foreignKey' => 'organisation_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );

$this->find('all',array(
        'fields' => array('IndicatorDatum.id','IndicatorDatum.indicator_id','IndicatorDatum.report_year_id','IndicatorDatum.value','IndicatorDatum.comment','IndicatorDatum.reference'
        ),'contain' => array(
            'ReportYears'),

        'conditions'=>array('IndicatorDatum.indicator_id' =>'2' , 'IndicatorDatum.organisation_id'=>$organisation_id),
        'order' => array('IndicatorDatum.report_year_id')


));
```

Comment: Set recursive to 1 (or higher) to load your relations too... That should give you the data from the related tables.

Comment: @Bob recursive is not a good idea, it will fetch all the unneccessary models/fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the exact fields for each model(including associated models), otherwise only the id is being returned (and it is good, because if it would be all the fields, what if you have some text column in the db with KBs of data - you do not want to retrieve it)

also, please pay attention, that by default(and by cake conventions) model names are singular, so, inside contain it should be `ReportYear` and not ReportYears.

here is the final query.

```
    $this->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'IndicatorDatum.id',
            'IndicatorDatum.indicator_id',
            'IndicatorDatum.report_year_id',
            'IndicatorDatum.value',
            'IndicatorDatum.comment',
            'IndicatorDatum.reference' 
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'ReportYear' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'ReportYear.id',
                    'ReportYear.year' // not sure what you have as a year field name
                ) 
            ) 
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'IndicatorDatum.indicator_id' => '2',
            'IndicatorDatum.organisation_id' => $organisation_id 
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'IndicatorDatum.report_year_id' 
        ) 
    )
    );
```